# how do i get the sender email from the input form nodemailer node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, backend, nodemailer

I want the from(sender email) part to be gotten from the input but it keeps giving me the same thing as the sender and receiver the same i.e it keeps showing the user as the sender and receiver.
**front end part**

```
            <p class="drop">Drop A Message</p>
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="" id="name" class="form-inputs" placeholder="Full Name" ><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="" id="email" class="form-inputs" placeholder="Email Address" ><br>
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="" id="subject" class="form-inputs" placeholder="Subject Of The Message"><br>
            <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
            <textarea name="" id="mainMessage" cols="30" rows="10" class="message_body" ></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="submit_btn">
            
        </form>
```

***NodeJS***

```
app.post('/', (req,res) =>{
    // console.log(req.body);

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        service:'Gmail',
        // host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        secure:false,
        auth: {
            user: 'horiyorrmi72@gmail.com',
            pass: 'password'
        }
    }))

    
    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to : "horla_tech@protonmail.com",
        subject: `${req.body.subject}`,
        text : req.body.message
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) =>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send('error');
            
        }else{
            console.log('Email sent' + info.response);
            res.send('success');

        }
    })
})


app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`server running on port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: Could you please show fronend part?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer
@nodemailer
·
Oct 22
Replying to
@horla_techs
**Gmail does not allow to send email through their servers as 3rd person. If you try to use any other email address than your own as the sender, Gmail will override it.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).